# Name an SSM parameter from a stack parameter within an SSM parameter name in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-ssm

I have a CDK app with a CloudFormation Stack Parameter something like:

```py
project_name_param = cdk.CfnParameter(
    self,
    "ProjectName",
    default="MyCoolProject",
)
```

Since multiple instances of this stack can be deployed, I'd like to create an [SSM Parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) with name based on this project name, to keep things organized.

In plain CloudFormation, this could be achieved achieved by e.g:

```yaml
  MyCoolResourceArnParam:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter'
    Properties:
      Description: ARN of this project's MyCoolResource
      Name: !Sub '/Projects/${ProjectName}/MyCoolResource'
      Type: String
      Value: !GetAtt MyCoolResourceArn
```

...But I'm struggling to figure out how I'd use the `project_id_param` object in CDK to achieve the same thing. For e.g. have tried and failed with various combinations similar to:

```py
input_bucket_ssm_param = ssm.StringParameter(
    self,
    "MyCoolResourceSSMParam",
    string_value=my_cool_resource.arn,
    description="...",
    parameter_name=cdk.Fn.sub(
        f"/Projects/{project_name_param.value_as_string}/MyCoolResource"
    ),
)
```

Probably I'm missing something basic as still pretty new to using CFn parameters in CDK - can anybody enlighten me on how it's supposed to work?

Comment: So what is happening? Any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops, found the problem!

`cdk.Fn` is unnecessary (the CDK should resolve the dynamic "token" anyway in string formatting), but as noted in [the StringParameter doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ssm/StringParameter.html) the `simple_name` parameter is required, when using a tokenized `parameter_name`.

```py
input_bucket_ssm_param = ssm.StringParameter(
    self,
    "MyCoolResourceSSMParam",
    string_value=my_cool_resource.arn,
    description="...",
    parameter_name=f"/Projects/{project_name_param.value_as_string}/MyCoolResource",
    simple_name=False,  # < Need this too!
)
```